# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in Android Java

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I am creating a training app that will include games. One of the games is a true or False quiz, where the user clicks true or false when a statement appears on screen.

Some of the statements work when I answer true or false but after a couple of statements, the app is terminated with an Index out of bounds error.

I have a class for the game, and a class for the statements and their corresponding answers.

When I run the app, after a few questions the app closes and I get these errors.

```
 Process: com.example.securityapp, PID: 28776
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at 

com.example.securityapp.industry_standards_questions.checkAnswer(industry_standards_questions.java:104)
        at com.example.securityapp.industry_standards_questions.access$000(industry_standards_questions.java:20)
        at com.example.securityapp.industry_standards_questions$2.onClick(industry_standards_questions.java:71)
```

```js
package com.example.securityapp;

import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewAnimator;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class industry_standards_questions extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView stmnt;
    ImageView image_true, image_false;
    Button points;

    Statements tfStatements;
    int statementsLength;

    ArrayList<Item> statementList;
    int currentStatement = 0;
    int grade = 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_industry_standards_questions);

        stmnt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statement_TV);

        image_true = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trueImage);
        image_false = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.falseImage);

        tfStatements = new Statements();
        statementsLength = tfStatements.tfStatements.length;

        statementList = new ArrayList<>();

        points = (Button) findViewById(R.id.final_score);

        for(int i = 0; i < statementsLength; i++){
            statementList.add(new Item(tfStatements.getStatment(i), tfStatements.getAnswer(i)));
        }

        Collections.shuffle(statementList);

        setStmnt(currentStatement);

        points.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                score();
            }
        });

        image_true.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentStatement++;
                if(checkAnswer(currentStatement)){
                    grade++;
                    if(currentStatement < statementsLength){
                        setStmnt(currentStatement);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        image_false.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentStatement++;
                if(!checkAnswer(currentStatement)){
                    grade++;
                    if(currentStatement < statementsLength){
                        setStmnt(currentStatement);

                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }

    // show Statement
    private void setStmnt(int number){
        stmnt.setText(statementList.get(number).getStatement());
    }

    //check is answer is right
    private boolean checkAnswer(int number){
        String answer = statementList.get(number).getAnswer();
        return answer.equals("true");
    }

    public void score(){
     Toast.makeText(this, "You scored " + grade + " points!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     grade = 0;
 }

}
```

```js
package com.example.securityapp;

public class Statements {

    public String tfStatements [] = {

            "10% of U.S. companies use the Cybersecurity Framework",
            "Prevent is an element within the framework",
            "Respond is an element within the framework",
            "Access control is a future priority",
            "Risk Assessment is a current priority",
            "Asset management is a current priority",
            "The framework can be customised",
            "By 2020, an estimated 70% of U.S. companies will use the framework"
    };

    public String tfAnswers [] = {
            "false",
            "false",
            "true",
            "false",
            "true",
            "true",
            "true",
            "false"

    };

    public String getStatment (int number) {
        return tfStatements[number];
    }

    public String getAnswer (int number) {
        return tfAnswers[number];
    }



}
```

---

This is the Statements Class

```js
package com.example.securityapp;

public class Statements {

    public String tfStatements [] = {

            "10% of U.S. companies use the Cybersecurity Framework",
            "Prevent is an element within the framework",
            "Respond is an element within the framework",
            "Access control is a future priority",
            "Risk Assessment is a current priority",
            "Asset management is a current priority",
            "The framework can be customised",
            "By 2020, an estimated 70% of U.S. companies will use the framework"
    };

    public String tfAnswers [] = {
            "false",
            "false",
            "true",
            "false",
            "true",
            "true",
            "true",
            "false"

    };

    public String getStatment (int number) {
        return tfStatements[number];
    }

    public String getAnswer (int number) {
        return tfAnswers[number];
    }



}
```

Comment: You have 8 statements...

Comment: @LucaMurra Of course it is. He has 8 statements numbered 0-7 and he is trying to access #8, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the `onClick` of your buttons, in this way:

```
image_true.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkAnswer(currentStatement)){
                    grade++;
                    if(currentStatement < statementsLength -1)
                        setStmnt(currentStatement);
                }
                currentStatement++;
            }
        });

image_false.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!checkAnswer(currentStatement)){
                    grade++;
                    if(currentStatement < statementsLength -1)
                        setStmnt(currentStatement);
                }
                currentStatement++;
            }
        });
```

With your code, when the user answer to the 8th question, you check the answer at position 8, but your tfAnswers' last element has index of 7.

However, there's something I don't understand in your code: this line:

```
String answer = statementList.get(number).getAnswer();
```

and, precisely, the calling of `getAnswer` on a `String`, without passing arguments, while the method definition is

```
public String getAnswer (int number) {
    return tfAnswers[number];
}
```

So with an `int` parameter, so I'd called it in this way:

```
String answer = tfStatements.getAnswer(number);
```

But I think that the errors aren't finished there, I'd use your methods in this way:

```
private boolean checkAnswer(int number, String givenAnswer){
    String answer = tfStatements.getAnswer(number);
    return answer.equals(givenAnswer);
}
```

And called in this way:

```
image_true.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkAnswer(currentStatement, "true"))
                    grade++;
                currentStatement++;
                if(currentStatement < statementsLength -1)
                    setStmnt(currentStatement)
            }
        });

image_false.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkAnswer(currentStatement, "false"))
                    grade++;
                currentStatement++;
                if(currentStatement < statementsLength -1)
                    setStmnt(currentStatement);
            }
        });
```

By the way, consider using this instead of your `tfAnswers`:

```
public boolean tfAnswers [] = {
            false,
            false,
            true,
            false,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            false

    };
```

And using a `static` `Statements` class.

Comment: I moved the currentStatement++ line to where you said, but am still having the same issue. I am being told the issue is with this line `        String answer = statementList.get(number).getAnswer();
`

Comment: It seems to be breaking when the statement starting "10% of U.S companies..." is asked and the statement "Risk Management"

Comment: Take a look at my edit, and write here if you've other things to resolve

Comment: So I had a play about and it seems to work now apart from one problem. I need to double click my buttons in order to get the next statement to appear, and after 8 clicks, the game stops and the score is displayed. Is there a way to make the imageviews only require a single button click

Comment: Yes, take a look at my kast edits, the previous answer was a bit wrong